# Deterministic quadratic variation for gaussian martingale process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I haven't any idea how to attack this problem:

Let $M$ a continuous martingale and a Gaussian process. Prove that there exists a (deterministic) continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $M^2_t-f(t)$ is a martingale.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint to get started: What would $f$ have to be?  (Maybe you can express it in terms of the covariance function of $M$.)

Comment: In my opinion $f(t)=E(M_t^2)$ but I haven't idea how to show it

Comment: I also know that such a function exists then $f(t)-f(s)=E(M_t^2-M^2_s)=E((M_t-M_s)^2)$

Comment: Can you give me a sketch of solution for the existence?

Comment: Yes, $f(t) = E[M_t^2]$ is right.  If $M_t^2-f(t)$ is a martingale (which, say, is zero at $t=0$) then $E[M_t^2 - f(t)] = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: But how can I show that f(t) exists?

Comment: Why need to be 0 at zero?

Comment: I am saying you should **define** $f(t) = E[M_t^2]$ and then try to show that this choice makes $M_t^2 - f(t)$ into a martingale.  There is no loss of generality in assuming $M_0^2 - f(0) = 0$ because you can add any constant to $f(t)$ without breaking the desired property.