# Let $(M_t)$ be a continuous square-integrable martingale with independent increments. Is $t \mapsto \mathbb E[M_t^2]$ continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm reading a remark at page 4 of [these](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf) lecture notes.

---

Let $\left(\mathcal{F}_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$be a filtration and $M=\left(M_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$be a continuous square-integrable martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.

**Reminder.** The quadratic variation of $M$ is the unique process $\left(\langle M\rangle_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$which is increasing, continuous and adapted to $\left(\mathcal{F}_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$, such that $\langle M\rangle_0=0$ a.s. and $\left(M_t^2-\langle M\rangle_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$is a martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.

**Lemma 1.1.** For all $t>s \geq 0$,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left(M_t-M_s\right)^2 | \mathcal{F}_s\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\langle M\rangle_t-\langle M\rangle_s | \mathcal{F}_s\right).
$$

**Remark.** In general, $\langle M\rangle_t$ is not deterministic, but when $M$ has independent increments, then $\langle M\rangle_t=\mathbb{E}\left(M_t^2\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(M_0^2\right)$ (and is therefore deterministic).

---

**My understanding** In other threads ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645286/show-that-for-a-continuous-gaussian-martingale-process-m-that-langle-m-m-r), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131544/showing-a-quadratic-variation-is-increasing-and-continuous-with-respect-to-time?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992081/deterministic-quadratic-variation-for-gaussian-martingale-process), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645286/show-that-for-a-continuous-gaussian-martingale-process-m-that-langle-m-m-r?rq=1), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252039/is-variance-continuous-for-gaussian-martingale-with-continuous-paths?rq=1)), the remark holds if in addition $M$ is a Gaussian process, i.e., if $M$ is Gaussian then $t \mapsto \mathbb{E}\left(M_t^2\right)$ is continuous.

> Could you confirm that the remark is not necessarily correct?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3945806/convergence-and-continuity-of-a-martingale?noredirect=1

Comment: @greyls The author of the question in that thread uses the fact that $(M_t^2, t\ge 0)$ is a sub-martingale and thus $M_t^2 \le \mathbb E [M_T^2 | \mathcal F_t] = \eta$ for all $t \in [0, T]$. It seems to me $\eta$ depends on $\mathcal F_t$ and thus on $t$. Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Comment: @greyls Please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633720/convergence-of-the-moments-of-a-square-integrable-martingale-with-respect-to-tim) question which formulates my above confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an elementary solution and does not involve concepts
like quadratic variation.

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be defined by $f(t)=E[M_{t}^{2}]$.
Let $t_{0}\in[0,\infty)$ be arbitrary. We go to show that $f$ is
continuous at $t_{0}$. Let $(t_{n})$ be an arbitrary sequence in
$[0,\infty)$ such that $t_{n}\rightarrow t_{0}$. Choose $T\in[0,\infty)$
such that $t_{n}\leq T$ for all $n$.

Claim 1: $\{M_{t}^{2}\mid t\in[0,T]\}$ is uniformly integrable. Note
that $\{E\left[M_{T}^{2}\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]\mid t\in[0,T]\}$
is uniformly integrable because it is a family of random variables
arising from taking conditional expectation of the integrable random
variable $M_{T}^{2}$. For each $t\in[0,T]$, by Jensen inequality,
$M_{t}^{2}=\left(E\left[M_{T}\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]\right)^{2}\leq E\left[M_{T}^{2}\mid\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$.
Therefore, $\{M_{t}^{2}\mid t\in[0,T]\}$ is uniformly integrable
too.

In particular, $\{M_{t_{n}}^{2}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly
integrable. Note that $M_{t_{n}}^{2}\rightarrow M_{t_{0}}^{2}$ pointwisely,
so $\int M_{t_{n}}^{2}\,dP\rightarrow\int M_{t_{0}}^{2}\,dP$. That
is, $f(t_{n})\rightarrow f(t_{0})$. This shows that $f$ is continuous
at an arbitrary point and hence is a continuous function.

Comment: Remark: The condition "independent increment" is irrelevant and is not needed.

Comment: But the assumption "independent increments" is crucial for the fact that $\langle M\rangle_t=\mathbb{E}\left(M_t^2\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(M_0^2\right)$, right?

Comment: @Analyst The task is to prove that $t\mapsto E(M_t^2)$ is continuous. We do not need anything related to quadratic variation. You may trace my proof.

Answer (score 2):

I refer to [this source, Theorem 2](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/06/16/continuous-processes-with-independent-increments/). Every $\mathbb{R}$-valued continuous process $X$ with independent increments is s.t. $X_t-X_s\sim \mathcal{N}(b_t-b_s,\Sigma_t-\Sigma_s)$ for unique continuous functions $b_t,\Sigma_t$ with $b_0=0,\Sigma_0=0$. Now consider a filtration $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ s.t. $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ for all $s<t$ and $\sigma(X_s,s\leq t)\subseteq \mathscr{F}_t,\,\forall t$. Then
$$E[X_t-X_s|\mathscr{F}_s]=E[X_t-X_s]=b_t-b_s$$
Therefore $X$ is a $\mathscr{F}_t$-martingale iff $b_t=0,\forall t\geq 0$. Suppose $X$ is also a $\mathscr{F}_t$-martingale. Then $E[X_t^2]=E[X_0^2]+\Sigma_t$, which is continuous.